# some CSS rules failing on iPad landscape

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries, viewport, landscape

I've made a responsive website using bootstrap and media queries to alter the CSS for various screen sizes.

I have a section which displays incorrectly on the iPad when landscape, but it works fine when I test it on a browser at the same viewport width.

I have a col-md-8 offset by 2 and within it there are 3 col-sm-4 divs with an image in each set to 100% width of parent container (which I have drawn an example of in the linked image). http://pasteboard.co/8J885OF.png
This is how it displays in the browser at both the same viewport with as a landscape iPad and for larger widths and is how it should be. It also resizes fine for narrower widths (the columns collapse etc) in the browser and on mobile.

But on iPad landscape the div/images positioning and width gets completely messed up (and becomes bigger than the viewport) and I can't figure out why. Here is what it looks like. http://pasteboard.co/8Jt4NZo.png

Other random bits of CSS also get ignored in this mode for some reason whilst other stylings are fine. The styling for some of the links for example gets ignored (usually white text and pink background with CSS3 hover effects, but instead becomes plain blue underlined text as if there is no CSS applied to it at all).

Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:

I'm sorry, I have just found a rogue # in the CSS file and removing this has fixed it. I thought I'd searched thoroughly to make sure it wasn't a typo problem but I must have missed it. Thanks all.

Comment: We need to see the code to figure out what is going on.

Comment: W3C CSS Validator... http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I have just found a rogue # in the CSS file and removing this has fixed it. I thought I'd searched thoroughly to make sure it wasn't a typo problem but I must have missed it. It's odd that it messed up the CSS only for the ipad and only in landscape mode and not for the browser.

Thanks all, hope I haven't wasted anyone's time.